# Подскажить какую использовать библиотеку для Detection face video для Android?

Tags: java, android, видео

Стоит задача найти лицо на видео для Андроид приложения. Какую библиотеку лучше использовать?

Comment: вы хоитите, чтобы кто-нибудь погуглил вместо вас?

Comment: Зачем минусовать-то? Что не так в вопросе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой `OpenCV`